# How to convert an audio file like mp3 to an mo3 file?

Tags: audio

I am trying to make a game and I need to convert an audio file like mp3, ogg or whatever to an mo3 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compress XM, S3M, IT and MOD files to MO3.
There is no way to convert MP3, WAV, OGG or FLAC to MO3, because the way of saving the audio is fundamentally different. It's like giving your computer a cd and asking it to write out the notes for all instruments, the lyrics and special effects.

Maybe this can help you, as somebody finds some hackings... http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=1953.0

Comment: I have the music as a IT format, how to convert it to MO3?

Comment: I have the music as a IT format, how to compress it to MO3?